# Thread created (detached) never executed

Tags: c, pthreads

I have written this code:

```
void* th (void* arg)
{
    sleep(1);
    for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"%d\t",i);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&thread,&attr,th,NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    return 0;
}
```

The detach state should make the thread not joinable, so it should run even after the main process is terminated.But it doesn't print the numbers, all I see is that the thread terminated without printing anything to stderr.
Why isn't the detached thread executed?

Comment: Can you try printing to a physical file instead?

Answer (score 6):

A `return` from the `main` thread is equivalent to an `exit` of the whole process, so your process will exit before your thread may even print anything. Use `pthread_exit` instead to terminate that thread.

Comment: And, judging by that `sleep(1)`, it probably won't get to execute anything else.

Comment: So also the main process is considered a thread? In this code there are two threads?

Comment: No, the process initially consists of one thread. After `pthread_create`, there are momentarily two threads. Then `main` returns, which implicitly calls `exit`, and the process ceases to exist.

Comment: Also, returning from `th` with `return NULL` is equivalent to `pthread_exit(NULL)`.  `pthread_exit` is useful to exit the thread from any function, like `exit` is useful to exit the program from any function. If you're in the program's `main` function or a thread's `start_routine` you can just return.